# Symfony2 - Tinymce resource js not found

Tags: symfony, tinymce

I try to use stfalcon_tinymce in my app, i follow the doc install but there is a problem when the page is loaded.

There are many javascript errors, no one resource js are loaded, there is this kind of error for each js file : http://rdva.dev/bundles/stfalcontinymce/vendor/tinymce/plugins/style/plugin.min.js 404 (Not found)
And it's normal because there no file with this path in my web/bundlesstfalcontinymce/vendor/tinymce/plugins folder...

I've made a composer.phar update on tinymce (dev-master), assets:install, assetic:dump and cache:clear.
Someone knows why i don't have these files ?

This is my config :

composoer.json

```
    "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "dev-master",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-php-connector": "1.1.1",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "dev-master",
```

config.yml

```
stfalcon_tinymce:
    include_jquery: false
    tinymce_jquery: true
    selector : ".tinymce"
    language: %locale%
    base_url: %base_url%
    # Custom buttons
    tinymce_buttons:
        stfalcon: # Id of the first button
            title: "Stfalcon"
            image: "http://stfalcon.com/favicon.ico"
    theme:
        # Simple theme: same as default theme
        simple:
        ...
        advanced:
            theme: "advanced"
            plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template"
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect"
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor"
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen"
            theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak"
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top"
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left"
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom"
            theme_advanced_resizing: true
            entity_encoding: "raw"
            file_browser_callback : elFinderBrowser
        # Medium number of enabled plugins + spellchecker
        medium:
           ...
        # BBCode tag compatible theme (see http://www.bbcode.org/reference.php)
        bbcode:
           ...

fm_elfinder:
    locale: %locale%
    editor: tinymce
    tinymce_popup_path: "asset[bundles/stfalcontinymce/vendor/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_popup.js]"
    showhidden: false
    fullscreen: true
    include_assets: true
    connector:
        debug: false # defaults to false
        roots:       # at least one root must be defined
            uploads:
                driver: LocalFileSystem
                path: uploads
                upload_allow: ['image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation']
            upload_deny: ['all']
            upload_max_size: 2M
```

layou.html.twig

```
{{ elfinder_tinymce_init() }}
{{ tinymce_init() }}
```

Someone can help me ?

Thks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.html.twig (http://pastebin.com/1Z0VKLrH)

change this

```
{% javascripts
    'bundles/nfidbusinessmeeting/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'
    'bundles/nfidbusinessmeeting/js/popin.js'
    'bundles/nfidbusinessmeeting/js/bo.js'
    'bundles/nfidbusinessmeeting/js/sorttable.js'
    'bundles/nfiduser/js/validator.js'
    'bundles/nfidpage/js/main.js'
    'bundles/nfidbusinessmeeting/js/jquery.validate.min.js'
    'bundles/nfidbusinessmeeting/js/jquery.validate.messages_fr.js'
    'bundles/ineattheming/js/colorpicker.js'
filter='yui_js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

to (make sure the bundle names are OK, I had to guess)

```
{% javascripts
    '@NfidBusinessMeetingBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'
    '@NfidBusinessMeetingBundle/Resources/public/js/popin.js'
    '@NfidBusinessMeetingBundle/Resources/public/js/bo.js'
    '@NfidBusinessMeetingBundle/Resources/public/js/sorttable.js'
    '@NfidUserBundle/Resources/public/js/validator.js'
    '@NfidPageBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js'
    '@NfidBusinessMeetingBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.validate.min.js'
    '@NfidBusinessMeetingBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.validate.messages_fr.js'
    '@IneatTheming/Resources/public/js/colorpicker.js'
filter='yui_js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: Can you post the full layout.html.twig for me?

Comment: Just check if the paths are OK, I don't know what you're filestructure is and what bundles you use. You can check with the developer tools in Chrome or use firebug which paths are used in the dev / prod environment

Comment: It's always the same, it try to load tinymce plugins, but some plugin are not found... "http://rdva.dev/bundles/stfalcontinymce/vendor/tinymce/plugins/advimage/plugin.min.js"   for this example, there is many folder in /plugins but not advimg. And this file structure is automatically generate whit assets and assetic, so what can i do ?

Comment: delete the plugin from the config.yml, create an issue on the github of stfalcon-tinymce and if it's possible fix it and create a pull request.

Comment: I found the problem... The bundle have been updated and the plugin name's have been changed ! So, it didn't find folders.